# Chrome Extension Words Replace

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I´m trying to do a simple extension for Google Chrome but i think that i have some mistakes. This extension replace a word for other word. Some users have similar questions but I can´t find the solution to my problem :$

This is html

```
  <button id="iniciar">Cambiar</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=cambiar.js></script>
```

This js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    "use strict";
    var palabra = document.getElementById('iniciar');

    palabra.addEventListener("click", function () {

        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("1", 'g'), "2");

    });
});
```

And this json

```
    {
    "name": "TextBreak"
    , "version": "0.1"
    , "manifest_version": 2
    , "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "flag.png"
        , "default_title": "TextBreak"
        , "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
    , "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
            , "js": ["cambiar.js"]
            , "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is your question? What is the bug detail?

Comment: When I install plugin and test it in a webpage, the extension don´t replace 1 to 2.

Comment: any error info in console?

Comment: Have you tried                        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("1", 'g'), "2");
});  ?

Comment: flagged too broad as there as too many conceptual errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole concept of your code is wrong. It seems that you don't understand the basics yet. I would suggest that you read about the [architecture of Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) before experimenting further.

**Errors in your code:**

1. [Content scripts are executed on the page that they are injected into](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). This means that you are trying to connect your function to an `"iniciar"` element on the target page, not on the popup.
2. Your content script is in no way connected to your popup page. It will get injected automaticaly on every matching page. If you want to trigger content script injection from popup, you need to use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).
3. Content scripts with `"run_at": "document_end"` are injected after the DOM has been created. This means that your `DOMContentLoaded` listener will never fire.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, now the extension works.

HTML.

```
 <button id="iniciar">Cambiar</button>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cambiar.js"></script>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var detectado = document.getElementById('iniciar');
        detectado.addEventListener('click', function() {   
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('1' , 'g'), '2');"});    

    });
});
```

JSON

```
  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
    , "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "flag.png"
        , "default_title": "Relaxing cup of café con leche"
        , "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
   "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["cambiar.js"]
        }
    ]
```